# Java 8 - Filter entry based on latest modification datetime from list (which having duplicate entries)

Tags: java-8

In my application I have page called process history which contains lots of process that can be duplicated.
Using Java 8 Steam() filter I'm successfully filter out process based on File Name and Action and get the resulting list. You can see below code and result.

Using Constructor and getter setter to add element in arraylist.

```
List<CurrentProcess> list = new ArrayList<>();
CurrentProcess addProcess = new CurrentProcess(strData1,strData2, strData3, date1 );
 list.add(addProcess);
```

//Constructor

```
public CurrentProcess(String fileName, String action, String status, Date startDate) {
    super();
    FileName = fileName;
    Action = action;
    Status = status;
    StartDate = startDate;
}

List<CurrentProcess> filterList = list.stream().filter(x -> ("Transfer".equalsIgnoreCase(x.getAction())&& "ABC_File".equalsIgnoreCase(x.getFileName()))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Result:

```
CurrentProcess [FileName=ABC_File, Action=Transfer, Status=Done, StartDate=Tue Jan 29 13:09:00 IST 2019]
CurrentProcess [FileName=ABC_File, Action=Transfer, Status=Done, StartDate=Tue Jan 29 13:09:00 IST 2019]
CurrentProcess [FileName=ABC_File, Action=Transfer, Status=Done, StartDate=Tue Jan 29 13:03:00 IST 2019]
```

Now I want to get entry based on latest datetime  from filterList using Stream() filter.

Please help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you want to retreive only one entry ( which have the latest date ) or many entries ?

Comment: Yes,only one entry with latest date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to preserve your `filterList`  you can do it like this :

```
LocalDate maxDate = filterList.stream()
                              .max(Comparator.comparing(CurrentProcess::getStartDate))
                              .get();
```

If you don't use `filterList` you can do it directly in the pipline :

```
LocalDate maxDate = list.stream()
                        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                        .filter(x -> ("Transfer".equalsIgnoreCase(x.getAction())&& "ABC_File".equalsIgnoreCase(x.getFileName())))
                        .max(Comparator.comparing(CurrentProcess::getStartDate))
                        .get();
```

**PS** :

- Feel free to change the type of `maxDate`.
- **To avoid NPE** : you can add `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` **before the first filter** (*to avoid too much test cases concatination in a single filter method*) or use the returned optional from `max` method then use that.

Comment: Thanks Abdelghani Roussi

Comment: @ Abdelghani Roussi  is their any way to get index position of entry which we retreived in above code?